# Find length of a chord of a circle with radius $13$ cm given position of a point located on the chord.

Tags: circles

A point located on a chord of a circle is 8 cm from one endpoint of the chord and 7 cm from the center of the circle. If a radius of this circle is 13 cm long, how long is the chord, in cm?

Please help! I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Can you check if the answer is 23cm?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Applying the Pythagorean theorem twice

$$h^2 = 7^2 - x^2 = 13^2 - (8+x)^2$$

where you have one right angled triangle
with sides $x$ and $h$ and hypotenuse $7$ and 
another right angled triangle
with sides $8+x$ and $h$ and the radius of
$13$ is the hyptenuse.

chord $= 2 \cdot (8+x)$

Comment: Or you can directly find out by Law of Cosines.